# how to lookup availability zone name from availability zone id?

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

In some places in my tf file, I am providing an `availability_zone_id`. E.g.

```
variable "az_id" { }

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "${var.subnet_cidr_block}"
  availability_zone_id = "${var.az_id}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
}
```

... and in the `my.tfvars` file:

```
az_id              = "euw2-az1"
```

In other places, I need to provide an `availablity_zone` name.  E.g.

```
resource "aws_ebs_volume" "controller-ebs-sdb" { 
  availability_zone = "${var.az}"  
  size              = 1024 
  type              = "gp2"
}
```

Is there a way in terraform to lookup the availability zone name from the availability zone id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a variable `az` and removing the `az_id`

```
az = "eu-west-2a"
```

... and adding a data element

```
data "aws_availability_zone" "main" {
  name = "${var.az}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "main" {                                          
  ...                          
  availability_zone_id = "${data.aws_availability_zone.main.zone_id}"   
  ...                                                                                                       
}  

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "controller-ebs-sdb" {
  availability_zone = "${var.az}"
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to get the availability zones that are supported on that region then use an index. Then can this index.

Example:

data "aws_availability_zones" "available_az" {}

Then on your resource use the following with index. If you want to use your 1st AZ then use index 0. If you want to use your 2nd AZ then use index 1.

availability_zone       = "${element(data.aws_availability_zones.available_az.names, 0)}"